# Install OpenCV for multiple Python versions in Linux

Tags: linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, cmake

I would like to install OpenCV with Python support on my Raspberry Pi for multiple versions of Python.

I am using the instructions at http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_Linux_install.html.  When OpenCV builds, it automatically targets python 3.4.  That is OK, but I would also like to also add support to Python 2.7.

I have seen instructions that utilize virtual environments (http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/), but don't want to use virtual environments.

How can I tell the OpenCV build / install to target specific or multiple versions of Python without using virtual environments? I assume there is a way to instruct CMake on what to build, but I know very little about how to use CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if CMake has to do with this, but I first I installed Python 2.7

`sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev`

Then I targetted python 2 to the virtual environment I made
`mkvirtualenv cv -p python2`

Afterwards, I checked and verified if it worked
`ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

It should display something like this after:

`total 1852
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 1895772 Mar 20 20:00 cv2.so`

Link to the guide I used: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to get an answer that doesn't use virtual environments (see question), but maybe I need to just go with virtual environments.

Comment: Np, it's definitely a good idea to seperate them into virtual environments so they can have independent compilers